# Postgres syntax error in command consistent with documentation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.6

I am attempting to add a column to a table in `postgres` version 9.6.2.

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.2
```

Accordingly, I am referencing the [`ALTER TABLE` documentation for `postgres 9.6`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html).

The documentation says:

> ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
>       action [, ... ]
>
> where action is one of:
>
> ```
> ADD [ COLUMN ] [ IF NOT EXISTS ] column_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]
> ```

I have a table `task`:

```
=> select * from task;
 id | name
----+------
(0 rows)
```

on which I want to insert a column `state` using an idempotent command (i.e. it checks for whether the `state` column has been created already). That command is:

```
ALTER TABLE task ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS state BIGINT NOT NULL;
```

However, this gives a syntax error at `NOT`:

```
=> ALTER TABLE task ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS state BIGINT NOT NULL;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NOT"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE task ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS state BIGINT NOT N...
```

Is this command inconsistent with the documentation? How do I resolve the syntax error?

Note: The command works without error when I remove the `IF NOT EXISTS` phrase, but the resulting command in that case is not idempotent as desired.

Comment: What does `select version();` say? Just because `psql` is from 9.6.2 doesn't mean that the server you're connecting to is 9.6.2.

Comment: @muistooshort you are right. `select version()` showed the version to be 9.4, and the documentation for 9.4 does not show a IF NOT EXISTS option for created columns. It seems I'll have to think of how to make the command idempotent without that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might write a stored function in Postgres < 9.6 for adding columns in a failure safe way. Here is a very simple version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_column(in_statement TEXT, in_table TEXT, in_column TEXT, in_schema TEXT DEFAULT 'public') RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $_$
BEGIN
    PERFORM * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = in_table AND column_name = in_column AND table_schema = in_schema;
    IF FOUND THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    ELSE
        EXECUTE in_statement;
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
END
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

You can add columns by;

```
SELECT add_column('ALTER TABLE task ADD COLUMN state BIGINT NOT NULL', 'task', 'state');
```

The schema name is optional and only needs to be specified if the schema is not `public`.